# Solr 4.0 group sorting - special cases

Tags: solr, solr4

My application has two main concepts, Developments and Plots. A development is an aggregation of plots. For context, developments are housing developments and plots are houses/flats within a development.

We are using Solr version 4.0.

We're using a group query (grouped by development id) to aggregate the plots into developments for search purposes and the following logic is to be used:
Sort developments by the lowest price plot in each development. If the development has a plot of price zero and no plots with a greater price, then that has highest priority; but if a development has a plot of price zero and a price greater than zero, then the lowest non-zero price should be used for sorting purposes.

Price is defined as:

```
<field name="price" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

I'm trying to implement this without modifying the schema and indexing the lowest price plot in the development against every plot in the development.

I've tried sort=map(price,0,0,999999999), which treats 0 priced plots as being much more expensive, which solves the problem of using the lowest non-0 price, but this doesn't solve the problem of having only a single 0 priced plot.

I've also tried group.sort=map(price,0,0,99999999) on the understanding that the group sort was based on the first item in the group, but this assumption appears not to be true.

Example data:

```
Development 1:
  Plot 1: Price 1000
  Plot 2: Price 10000
Development 2:
  Plot 3: Price 5000
  Plot 4: Price 8000
Development 3:
  Plot 5: Price 0
  Plot 6: Price 15000
Development 4:
  Plot 7: Price 0
```

In this scenario the correct sort is:

```
Developments: 4, 1, 2, 3
```

Please let me know if there's a way to solve this.

*It should be noted that users are able to filter by price range and the above logic still needs to work in the filtered result set.